# Navigation problems in jquery1.4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a 3 page structure like this:

```
index.html
test.html
folder1/page1.html
```

I use this script for navigation:

```
 $(".navigate").on("vclick", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.navigate($(this).attr("id")+".html");
    });
```

Each page has a link like this:

```
index.html => <a class="navigate" id="test">TEST</a>
test.html => <a class = "navigate" id="folder1/page1">PAGE1</a>
```

All navigations use `Ajax transitions.`

The problem is when I navigate to `page1.html` via `index.html -> test.html` and from `page1.html`, if I navigate back to `index.html` using the browser back button and again navigate to `page1.html` as stated above my `page1.html`, it automatically redirects back to `events.html`, but the URL will be showing the proper address of `page1.html`

What is happening here?

Comment: where is the events.html --- 3 page structure index.html, test.html, folder1/page1.html

Comment: use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "url")` instead of `$.mobile.navigate()`.

Comment: @Omar: I tried it Omar but it does not work. It navigates according to its own wish. I am fed up with this navigation quirks in jqm1.4.

Comment: Add `data-dom-cache="true"` to page div for all pages. Try again.

Comment: @Omar Still does not work. Can I have your email? I will narrate the problem more deeply.

Comment: I dont think it's allowed to exchange emails here. you can update your question with whatever details you want, also, upload data to dropbox so I can access it.

Comment: why dont use `href="page.html"` instead of `changePage`? and still can run any code you want during transition.

Comment: But the lag for the click event that is not acceptable. I am building a phonegap app. I dont want to use external libraries like fastclick.js.

Comment: I ill try moving this to chat