# how to enable data-ajax = false for dynamic navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

```
$(".someClass").on("vclick", function(){
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer ("change", "test.html", {reloadPage: true});
});
```

How do I make this navigation without `ajax.`

I dont want to set the global `mobileinit` configuration.

Comment: As of JQM 1.4, use `reload`.

Comment: you mean just reload and not reloadTrue?

Comment: I meant `reload: true` but the page should be an URL and make sure all libraries are places on head of the page.

Comment: I tried that! But even reload:true does not work. It is still working as ajax transition

Comment: Why have they made navigation so horrible Omar? 1.3.2 was just fine. I am choosing no ajax navigation because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588061/navigation-problems-in-jquery1-4-1

Comment: Using changePage function will reload target page, meaning will remove everything in DOM and replace them with target page's content, even "head" contents. I'll double check it anyway.

Comment: Yeah I tried it. $.mobile.changePage("test.html", {reload:true}); But it does not work. Still it is regular ajax navigation.

Comment: And other problem is, consider a panel widget with links inside that for site navigation. When I navigate to home and sports pages a couple of times then suddenly the pages auto-navigate. That is if I click on home link in sports page then the home page appears and suddenly slides away and displays the sports page itself. How come all this happens?

Comment: `reload: true` works with `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer()` not `$.mobile.changePage()`. I haven't got the chance to check it really, I will try to do it soon.

Comment: I tried it with $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer() too but still it is not working

Comment: `window.location = "url";` should fix it for now.

Comment: I want to use jquery's navigation. Not default JS. Is that a bug?